# Do C# await continuations create new threads?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await, continuation

As the question says.  I'd like to know if simply calling `await` in code has the potential to create a new thread.

Let's assume it's during a console app.

Comment: It depends what you're awaiting.  Read http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/05/08/eduasync-part-1-introduction.aspx

Comment: "await" is about asynchrony.  Multiple threads are only *one* way to do asynchrony.

Comment: Of course, I'm just inquiring as to the runtime's attitude towards receiving `Task` instances and whether it makes any decisions for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft's .NET 4.5 `Task` implementation will first try to invoke `await`-based continuations inline (i.e., on whatever thread completes the task).  If it can't be executed inline (e.g., due to stack depth or use of a `SynchronizationContext`) the system thread pool is used instead.  It won't *explicitly* create a new thread, though it might trigger the creation of a new thread in the pool.

See `System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation` in the reference sources for details.

Note that this answer **only** applies to an awaited `Task`, and only on the Microsoft .NET 4.5 Framework.  Also, if you are awaiting from a thread with a `SynchronizationContext`, and you are not using `ConfigureAwait(false)`, then it would depend on the `SynchronizationContext` implementation.  No new threads should be created for a WinForms, WPF, or Silverlight `SynchronizationContext`.

Comment: Any insights when running on Mono?

Comment: None, I'm afraid.  It's open source, so you can certainly poke around, but I have not done so.

Comment: Heh, finding out via the source is likely well over my head, I just figured I'd ask ;)

Comment: I can say that I'd be *very surprised* if any `Task` implementation explicitly created a new thread just to invoke a continuation.  Unless, of course, you specify `TaskContinuationOptions.LongRunning` when registering the continuation, but using `await` never does that (as far as I know).  This is completely anecdotal.